# Datatype Mismatch - When Sorting Access SQL "Top N" Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, top-n

### My BASE Code

I have a set of data that, where I wanted to grab the `Top N` with highest `SumOfAmount` values, FOR EACH `Status Detail` value. To do this, I used:

```
SELECT 
  [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].[Status Detail], 
  [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].Insurance, 
  [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].[CountOfInvoice No], 
  [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].SumOfAmount
FROM [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1]
WHERE (([Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].SumOfAmount In 
  (
   SELECT TOP 3 SumOfAmount 
   FROM [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1] as t 
   WHERE t.[Status Detail] = [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].[Status Detail] 
   ORDER By SumOfAmount DESC))
  );
```

NOTE: Using the `WHERE` subselect allowed me to get the FOR EACH `Status Detail` element of my query. Simply using `SELECT TOP 3` would only provide me with top 3 charges overall.

### My Problem

Long story short - it looks like the order required by the `WHERE` subselect criteria is preventing further sorting in the primary query.

Now that I have the results I want, I'm trying to display them properly. I'm trying to sort by `Status Detail`. I tried posting my code here, but it wouldn't format properly - the code was simply the "My BASE Code" above, plus, right between the final `)` and `;` was:

```
ORDER BY [Status Detail];
```

When executing this query, I get the error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

### Troubleshooting

I've tried:

1. Adding the `ORDER BY` statement directly to the query (see stated above). This results in the "data type mismatch" error.
2. Using a report, and sorting the report by `Status Detail`. I still get the same error.
3. Using a second query built from this query's results, and sorting that. I still get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the sub query independently on its own query and pass the [Report_SubstatusVsInsurance_Top3_Q, Part 1].[Status Detail] as a parameter? (Just to test if it runs correctly) sometimes accesss does some weird things that dont really make sense

Comment: @Erick3E - I had tried that and unfortunately it didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though!